# on click of link not firing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what i am missing but when i click on my anchor i am not hitting the javascript within it. Here is my layout:

view:

```
<a id="Add" href="#" class="btn float_right addingUsers"> Add User </a>
```

In my Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'addingUsers', function (event) {
            $.views.Project.getAdditions(event.Id);
        });
```

When i tried debugging i couldn't get to 'getAdditions' unless that means there is something wrong with that function call. Not sure what other information is needed so please feel free to demand more code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the dot.  For a class name jQuery selector, you want a dot followed by the classname.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addingUsers', function (event) {
    $.views.Project.getAdditions(event.Id);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Missing `.` in your class selector

```
$(document).on('click', '.addingUsers', function (event) {
    //...................^...........
    event.preventDefault();
    $.views.Project.getAdditions(event.Id);
});
```

Also add `event.preventDefault();` for preventing the browser default action

Answer (score 2):

`addingUsers` is a class, what you have there is just a string so make it a class `.addingUsers`

```
$(document).on('click', '.addingUsers', function (event) {
      $.views.Project.getAdditions(event.Id); // wrong way to obtain elements id BTW. It's been addressed above.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addingUsers', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.views.Project.getAdditions(event.Id);
    });
```

you have miss  a `.` in selector and you need the `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you http://jsfiddle.net/8QpGa/

**HTML**

Add User

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addingUsers").on('click', function (event) {
   $(".test p").append($(this).attr("id")+"<br/>");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/Mkw6v/)

```
$(function(){
   $( "#Add.addingUsers" ).on( "click", function() {
       alert( $( this ).text() );
   });
});
```